# Symfony 1.4 & APC - "The apc extension must be loaded for using this backend!"

Tags: php, symfony1, symfony-1.4, apc, ubuntu-12.04

I just installed apc (lates stable / latest beta), phpinfo() shows the apc-module.
If I do a symfony cc I get the message
"  The apc extension must be loaded for using this backend !  "

I put this in my app's configuration Class:

```
public function configureDoctrine(Doctrine_Manager $manager)
{
  $manager->setAttribute(Doctrine::ATTR_QUERY_CACHE, new Doctrine_Cache_Apc());
}
```

and this in my php.ini:

```
extension=apc.so
```

It worked fine on my development-system but does not on the web-server. What's the cause of this problem?

PHP-Version:
PHP 5.3.10-1ubuntu3.4 with Suhosin-Patch (cli) (built: Sep 12 2012 18:59:41) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2012 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.3.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2012 Zend Technologies

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, got it.
I needed to add "extension=apc.so" to the php.ini for the comand-line (/etc/php5/cli/php.ini), too.

Comment: How to load the same extension for Windows 8 with Wamp Server.
I have set extension but not loaded.